How to call a suspend function on a Preview Composable?
I'm trying to preview a composable with data that is returned from a suspend function which can be accessed throught a repository stored on Application class.
This is the suspend function:
marsPhotosRepository.getMarsPhotos()

I know that LaunchedEffect should be used to call suspend functions on Composables, so I did this:
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ResultScreenPreview() {
    MarsPhotosTheme {
        val marsPhotosRepository = (LocalContext.current.getActivity()?.application as MarsPhotosApplication).container.marsPhotosRepository
        LaunchedEffect(true) {
            PhotosGridScreen(marsPhotosRepository.getMarsPhotos())
        }
    }
}

It is giving me this error:

@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
@Composable function


Does this answer your question? Error: "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"

You can't call any Composable function inside LaunchedEffect but you can have nullable data, fill it inside LaunchedEffect and show PhotosGridScreen whe data is not null.
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ResultScreenPreview() {
    MarsPhotosTheme {
        val marsPhotosRepository = (LocalContext.current.getActivity()?.application as MarsPhotosApplication).container.marsPhotosRepository

        var data by remember { mutableStateOf<MyData?>(null) }

        LaunchedEffect(true) {
            data = marsPhotosRepository.getMarsPhotos())
        }

        data?.let{PhotosGridScreen(it)}
    }
}


your code doesn't compile, and if I try to make it compile, I get exactly the same error. Please, can you test it? Also, take in mind that getMarsPhotos returns List. Bytheway, I switched to mutableStateListOf and added some } to make it compileable but as I told you, don't compile and give the same error.

This is pseudocode. Of course there is no MyData class and without providing a repdoducible code how can you expect it to be testable? It's an example to show how you can implement it

What you need to is having a nullable data or a class data has States such as Empty, Loading, Success, etc. Check if data is available and fill data inside launchedEffect via a suspendable function. It doesn't matter what kind of data you have

maybe there are a lot of errors in the pseudocode? I have to replace by remember with = remember, and a lot of changes, also, after making it compiling, I got another error: Type mismatch.
Required:
SnapshotStateList
Found:
List on data = marsPhotosRepository.getMarsPhotos()). I'm stuck trying to make work your answer, please can you help me improving it?

I see that one bracket is missing but what you need to do is passing same data type to PhotosGridScreen you  get from repository. Only trick here is using nullable data and updating it inside LaunchedEffect.

I think produceState would be much simpler than MutableState plus LaunchedEffect.
